# Regex test works but breaks when it's passed to HTML5 input pattern attribute

Tags: regex, html, validation, input

I'm trying to use this pattern on a password field that says "Password should be min 6 chars and contain 1 non-alphabet character":

```
^(?=.{6})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])
```

However when passing this into the `pattern` attribute it stops working. Check this demo:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", onFormSubmit);

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pwEl = document.querySelector('.password');
  
  alert('With pattern: ' + pwEl.checkValidity() + ', without pattern: ' + /^(?=.{6})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/.test(pwEl.value));
}
```

```html
<form novalidate>
  
  <input class="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter password" pattern="^(?=.{6})(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])" />
  
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  
</form>
```

Try entering:

- "password" both are false
- "password1" pattern is false but regex with the same pattern works

Comment: The pattern attribute must match the full string, yours matches only an empty string. Add `.*` at the end to solve the problem. Note that the pattern in the pattern attribute is implicitly anchored, you can remove the `^` anchor at the beginning or write it this way: `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z]).{6,}`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte great it works and I prefer your suggested one! thanks, please copy that over to an answer so I can accept it

Comment: This pattern `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z]).{6,}` works in pattern attribute.